# How to convert a multivariate abundance matrix into a occurrence table in R?

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have a multivariate abundance matrix (species abundances by sites):

```
Site<-c("1","2","3","4","5","6")
Long<-c("30.01565","29.99297","29.98867","29.95418","29.96438","29.93963")
Lat<-c("-29.71932","-29.69708","-29.70216","-29.65436","-29.66999","-29.66700")
Sp_A<-c("0","0","3","3","0","8")
Sp_B<-c("3","7","1","0","0","0")
Sp_C<-c("1","0","5","0","3","6")
Sp_D<-c("5","4","3","3","4","4")
data<-cbind(Site,Long,Lat,Sp_A,Sp_B,Sp_C,Sp_D)
```

```
     Site Long       Lat         Sp_A Sp_B Sp_C Sp_D
[1,] "1"  "30.01565" "-29.71932" "0"  "3"  "1"  "5" 
[2,] "2"  "29.99297" "-29.69708" "0"  "7"  "0"  "4" 
[3,] "3"  "29.98867" "-29.70216" "3"  "1"  "5"  "3" 
[4,] "4"  "29.95418" "-29.65436" "3"  "0"  "0"  "3" 
[5,] "5"  "29.96438" "-29.66999" "0"  "0"  "3"  "4" 
[6,] "6"  "29.93963" "-29.66700" "8"  "0"  "6"  "4"
```

I need to use this matrix and create a new table/matrix. The new table should have 4 columns, specifically, Species, Long, Lat, and Presence. For this table, I do not care about the abundance values, but rather whether a particular species is present or absent at a locations. So the new table will have multiple duplicates of a single species, at different locations, being present and absent at those locations. The table should look like this. Example for Sp_A only:

```
##    Species   Long        Lat         Presence
## 1  Sp_A      30.01565    -29.71932   0 #Binary meaning absent
## 2  Sp_A      29.99297    -29.69708   0
## 3  Sp_A      29.98867    -29.70216   1 #Binary meaning present
## 4  Sp_A      29.95418    -29.65436   1
## 5  Sp_A      29.96438    -29.66999   0
## 6  Sp_A      29.93963    -29.66700   1
```

Other words, for every species in die multivariate abundance matrix, I want to create separate records for every observation. How can I automate this process in R with a function? My data formatting skills are very rusty. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Why your values are stored in matrix as strings/characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  select(-Site) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Sp'), values_to = 'Presence') %>%
  mutate(Presence = pmin(Presence, 1)) %>%
  arrange(name)

#    Long   Lat name  Presence
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1  30.0 -29.7 Sp_A         0
# 2  30.0 -29.7 Sp_A         0
# 3  30.0 -29.7 Sp_A         1
# 4  30.0 -29.7 Sp_A         1
# 5  30.0 -29.7 Sp_A         0
# 6  29.9 -29.7 Sp_A         1
# 7  30.0 -29.7 Sp_B         1
# 8  30.0 -29.7 Sp_B         1
# 9  30.0 -29.7 Sp_B         1
#10  30.0 -29.7 Sp_B         0
# … with 14 more rows
```

**data**

```
data<-data.frame(Site,Long,Lat,Sp_A,Sp_B,Sp_C,Sp_D)
data <- type.convert(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Ronak. My species names are oversimplified in the example data set above. Every species name starts with a different letter, so the ```cols = starts_with('Sp')``` will not work.

Comment: So how do you know which columns has species information? You can also use column numbers as `cols = 3:6`.

Comment: The first 3 columns of the matrix has location and ID data, the rest of the matrix is species information. The ```cols=3:6``` should work. Let me try.

Comment: You can also use `cols = -(1:2)` to ignore 1st 2 columns. (I have already removed `Species` column with `select`).

Comment: Some of my other loaded libraries are conflicting with ```select```. However, your solution works perfectly. Thanks so much Ronak :)

Comment: How would I change your code to retain the abundance data in the original matrix (Through duplicating the binary records in the occurrence table)? E.g. If a species has an abundance value of 3 in the original table, how do I create 3 presence records in the new table, instead of the one in the code above? @Ronak

Comment: I don't think I understand completely. Probably it is better to ask it as a new question with example data and expected output so that it can be answered separately.